# Webpack add code on production

Tags: javascript, webpack

I need to add some code to bundle on production mode. I have two separated webpack configs. Is there a simple way to add file.js to bundle in configuration?

Comment: Do you want to execute code differently, or add another entry point?

Comment: I need part of code to be added on production. Lets say  I want to add console.log('production').

Answer (score 0):

Requiring the .js in the production webpack config file, and including it to the exports:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {   plugins: [
    new UglifyJSPlugin()   ] });
```

example code source:

> https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/